# Padding inside Expanded

Tags: android, flutter, padding

I need to create a full screen table using Flutter. Since I wasn't able to do so with `Table`/`DataTable` I'm trying with `Flex`/`Expanded`.

Everithing works as expected, but I can't style `Expanded`'s `child`, so for instance it seems I cannot set a padding.

This is my code so far.

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Calendar2(),
    );
  }
}
```

`calendar2.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Calendar2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Calendar2State();

}

class _Calendar2State extends State<Calendar2> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<CalendarRow> tableRows = buildTable();
    print(tableRows);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: tableRows,
      )
    );
  }

  List<CalendarRow> buildTable() {
    List<CalendarRow> rows = <CalendarRow>[];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
      List<Widget> children = [];
      for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
        children.add(
          CalendarCell(
            child: Text((i * 7 + j + 1).toString())
          )
        );
      }
      rows.add(
        CalendarRow(
          children: children
        )
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }

}

class CalendarCell extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget child;

  CalendarCell({this.child}) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded (
      flex: 1,
      child: Padding(
        child: child,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), // this doesn't work for top and bottom
      )
    );
  }
}

class CalendarRow extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];

  CalendarRow({this.children}) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: children
      )
    );
  }
}
```

How can I style `child` inside `Expanded`?

Comment: Why do you extends `Expanded`? Make a statelessWidget and use composition instead

Comment: @RémiRousselet Because `Expanded` already has the feature I'm looking for (expansion over width/height).

Comment: I don't think you get it. Here's a pastebin https://pastebin.com/Dy78nzQV

Comment: @RémiRousselet Ok I got it, but what's the benefit here? You just have one more element in the tree, which is useless (you don't write `StatelessWidget`s when creating layouts, you create specific components like `Extended`).

Comment: Extending widgets is bad practices. StatelessWidget exists for this purpose. There are too many downsides with this syntax that I can't reasonnably explain it in comments. But the FAQ is pretty clear on that topic: Use composition instead of inheritance https://flutter.io/faq/ see "Can I extend and customize the bundled widgets?"

Comment: @RémiRousselet Ok, that's clear now, thanks. Any clues on my issue?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I updated the question. Actually introducing `StatelessWidget` solved the padding issue for the left side, it still doesn't let me edit the padding for top and bottom.

Comment: Your example shows a padding of 0. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @RémiRousselet It's supposed to have a 0 padding, but the item still has top and bottom padding.

Comment: So, did you check the answer, find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 18):

**This is how padding is done with Expanded widget in flutter**

```
    class DicePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
       child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(
          child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CalendarCell doesn't have vertical padding.
In CalendarRow you are using Expanded, so all your rows expanded through screen. Use Flexible instead

```
class Calendar2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Calendar2State();

}

class _Calendar2State extends State<Calendar2> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<CalendarRow> tableRows = buildTable();
    print(tableRows);

    return Scaffold(
        body: Flex(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: tableRows,
        )
    );
  }

  List<CalendarRow> buildTable() {
    List<CalendarRow> rows = <CalendarRow>[];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
      List<Widget> children = [];
      for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
        children.add(
            CalendarCell(
                child: Text((i * 7 + j + 1).toString())
            )
        );
      }
      rows.add(
          CalendarRow(
              children: children
          )
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }

}

class CalendarCell extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  CalendarCell({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded (
        flex: 1,
        child: Padding(
          child: child,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), // this doesn't work for top and bottom
        )
    );
  }
}

class CalendarRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;

  CalendarRow({this.children = const <Widget>[]});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
        child: Flex(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: children
        )
    );
  }
}
```